# update a column with cursor it returns the same values in column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table calendar_dates5 and calendar_dates4 I want to update all rows of calendar_dates4 with same dates as in calendar_dates4 dt column in 2nd column of dt2 there are difference is that only time dt have different time and dt2 have a different time but dates are same when i run with cursor I get same one figure in all column like this

```
DT                                     DT2  

1/1/2020 8:58:06 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM           
1/2/2020 8:55:40 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM           
1/3/2020 8:46:06 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM           
1/4/2020 8:59:58 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM           
1/5/2020 8:47:50 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM           
1/6/2020 8:46:39 AM             12/31/2020 4:57:01 PM
```

What I want is like that

```
1/1/2020 8:58:06 AM             1/1/2020 4:48:46 PM         
1/2/2020 8:55:40 AM             1/2/2020 4:50:48 PM         
1/3/2020 8:46:06 AM             1/3/2020 4:48:29 PM         
1/4/2020 8:59:58 AM             1/4/2020 4:49:26 PM         
1/5/2020 8:47:50 AM             1/5/2020 4:52:12 PM         
1/6/2020 8:46:39 AM             1/6/2020 4:51:33 PM
```

My query is

```
DECLARE  
   V_DT CALENDAR_DATES5.DT%TYPE;  
   CURSOR C_DT is  
      SELECT DT FROM CALENDAR_DATES5 ORDER BY DT;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN C_DT;  
   LOOP  
   
      FETCH C_DT into V_DT ;
      EXIT WHEN C_DT%notfound;
      UPDATE CALENDAR_DATES4
      SET DT2 = V_DT2;    
END LOOP;  
CLOSE C_DT;  
END;
```

Please Help me

Comment: I find your description to be very confusing, have no idea what you are getting at.  That said, I can tell you that your UPDATE statement, having no WHERE clause, will update _every_ row in the table calendar_dates4.  I doubt that is what you want.  Also, as a general rule I'd lose the declared cursor and just go with a "cursor for loop" ie:  for c_dt in (select ...... ) loop ...

Comment: @EdStevens I Tried with for loop like this `BEGIN
  FOR C_DT IN (
        SELECT DT FROM CALENDAR_DATES5 ORDER BY DT
    )
  LOOP
     UPDATE CALENDAR_DATES4
      SET DT2 = C_DT.DT;
  END LOOP;
END;
COMMIT;` but get same result mean all rows are updated with the only one dates

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that a cursor FOR loop would give you a different result. I was just pointing out that it is a cleaner way of handling cursors.    I also pointed out that an UPDATE without a WHERE will apply the update to _every_ row in the table, and you have not addressed that problem, either.

Answer (score 0):

Now may be I was not tried to elaborate fully question but how i get it this I made a form and then on button I applied this and saved from forms

```
Declare
    Cursor C_ID 
      is
      Select DT
             from hr.CALENDAR_DATES5;
             
begin
    go_block('CALENDAR_DATES4');
    
    clear_block(no_validate);
    
    first_record;
    for cur in C_ID loop
         :CALENDAR_DATES4.DT2 := cur.DT;
         
         next_record;
    end loop;
    
    first_record;
    
    end;
```

I know this is not how to do but what we can do when nothing is happened :)

Comment: "_what we can do when nothing is happened_"  But something _did_ happen.  If you tried to run that, you received a bunch of error messages. That code has more errors than an early Mets game.  And while I'll be the first to complain that the structure of SO should allow formatted code in replies, you should not use "answers" as a means of posting formatted replies. Just add it as an update to your opening post. And PLEASE READ THIS:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are that 'first_record;' and 'next_record;' statements supposed to accomplish? What is ':CALENDAR_DATES4.DT2 := cur.DT;'  supposed to be doing?    The colon in front of CALENDAR_DATES4.DT2 indicates it is a bind variable.  (one which doesn't exist, btw).  So all you are doing inside the loop is trying to assign the value of a variable from the cursor to some non-existent bind variable.

Comment: @EdStevens Dear I already told first that I use oracle forms to do this that bind variable understood that comes from fields

Comment: _" I use oracle forms to do this that bind variable understood that comes from fields"_  So you want to (repeatedly)  assign the bind variable a value derived from your cursor.  And then do nothing with it?  And what of those 'first_record'/'next_record' statements?  What are they supposed to do?  If you want any further help, you need to read (and heed) the link I provided you about creating a reproducible test.  At this point we really don't know what you have, what errors you are getting, where you want to get to, and why.